# Calculating scores and displaying total

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, addition, scoring

At the moment my system calculates the percentage of each check box and displays below the progress bar. The value element of each check box is already taken by the percentage ammount, so I am struggling on what to do regarding calculating the scores as well as the task percentage. Any ideas?.

As you can see the value fields of the checkboxes are taken up by the percentage.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" id="checkbox-0" value="15" class="hidden-checkbox">
```

Here is a jFiddle of the code I am working with:
[jsfiddle.net/UznQe/8](http://jsfiddle.net/UznQe/8)

Comment: What is exactly the problem? And what are the **scores** you want to calculate?

Comment: Aplogies for the vague question, if you check the fiddle you can see that the value of the checkboxes are taken up by the percentage, I want to be able to calculate the scores on each checkbox along with the percentage. I cant do this because the value tag is already being used by the percentage number. For example, if i checked 3 boxes, and they all had 10pts each, i would then want the total of them all to show, which would be 30.

Comment: The behavior becomes broken if you select everything and then start unselecting the boxes. You should refractor your code in a event listner, a calculation logic part and an status bar update

Comment: I know this thanks, I am planning on fixing that issue later.

Comment: ah I see, the 'score' value is not the same as the percentage value. You could use additional data atributes

Comment: Do you have any tips to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I've added a data atribute to the input fields

```
data-score="10"
```

and read the value like so

```
 perc = 0;
 score = 0;
 $("#theList input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function( index ) {
     perc += parseInt($(this).val());       
     score += parseInt($(this).data("score"));
 });

 $("span#progressText").text(perc + ' %');
 $("#progressScore").text(score);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UznQe/9/